# How is the frenet frame along an asymptotic curve related to the geometry of the surface?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading Differential Geometry: A first course in curves and surfaces by Theodore Shifrin and here is one of the questions from the exercise. I just can't seem to make the connection between the two.

Comment: Mathematics not statistics?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It's preferred form to put the actual question *in* the question, not the title. :) Also, you should give some indication about what you've tried. Given that I wrote the text, I have some idea of what tools you have available :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Assuming $\kappa\ne 0$, so that the Frenet frame actually is defined, if the curve is an asymptotic curve, what is $\kappa\mathbf N\cdot\bf n$? (Here $\mathbf N$ is the principal normal and $\mathbf n$ is the surface normal.)

Comment: will $\kappa\mathbf N\cdot\bf n=\kappa$ because both the normal unit vectors are in the same direction?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Why do you say that? What is the definition of an asymptotic curve, by the way?

Comment: An asymptotic curve is always tangent to the asymptotic direction, which is the direction in which the normal curvature is zero. So if the normal curvature of a surface in that direction is zero, and a curve is on the surface going in that direction, then the normal unit vector of the curve must also not be changing.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom No, that last statement is wrong. Yes, normal curvature is $0$. So what does that have to  do with the question I posed?

Comment: The normal curvature is zero, and therefore $\kappa \bf N \cdot n=0$ so the unit normal vectors of the curve and surface will be parallel!! Hurray for reading your notes!

Comment: Um, thanks, but review basics about dot product!

Comment: perpendicular!!